# Represent Is"Something" Data in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Joe Celko (sql guru) says that we should not use proprietary data types and especially refrain from machine level things like bit or byte since SQL-Server uses a high level language.  Basically that the principle of data modeling is data abstraction.  So discerning the above recommendation for fields like "IsActive" etc., what would the correct choice be for the data type, one that is a very portable and one that is deciphered clearly by front end layers? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, assuming the only two possible values are "Yes" and "No".

Comment: `Boolean` seems reasonable to me though its implementations differ between SQL dialects.

Comment: @Jarvis . . . Sounds like a good idea if your database supports `boolean`.  Not all do.  Your question would be better if it said:  "I want to represent boolean flags in a particular database.  What is the best way?" -- then also tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: For SQL Server one would use a BIT with the added benefit of storage optimization.  You could store the words (varchar2) 'True' or 'False' or even use an integer type (0,1).  But those are less efficient.  I would disagree with Joe on this one for SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Gordon I edited to specify the product in question.

Comment: I'd like to see the article you're citing. I suspect it's rather old. IMHO you should model data to fit what makes sense. To most, a `bit` is a true / false proposition. I'd go with `bit` in the database and `Boolean` in application code.

Comment: There is no Boolean data type in SQL Server. BIT is not a Boolean, it's a numeric type.

Comment: Unfortunately, `BOOLEAN` is neither a core, nor a required feature of the ISO SQL standard. Worse, none of the three leading professional SQL products implement it.  `BIT` is about as close as you come.

Comment: Thanks for the correction about Boolean types!

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, I would go for `BIT` data type as it matches the abstract requirements that you  describe: it can have 2 values (which map to Yes and No by a widely used convention of Yes = 1 and No = 0). It can have an additional NULL value if desired.

If possible, using native data types has all the benefits of performance, clarity and understandability for others. Not to mention the principle of not overcomplicating things when you can keep them simple.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't have a Boolean data type so Boolean is out of the question. BIT is a **numeric** type that accepts the values 0 and 1 as well as null. I usually prefer a CHAR type with a CHECK constraint permitting values like "Y"/"N" or "T"/"F". CHAR at least lets you extend the set of values to more than just two if you want to.

BIT has the potential disadvantage that it's non-standard, not particularly user-friendly and not well understood even by SQL Server users. The semantics of BIT are very peculiar in SQL Server and even Microsoft's own products treat BIT in inconsistent ways.